# How to use URN URI

Tags: http, web, resources, uri, urn

I know the difference between URI, URL and URN

I know that URN is a URI that identifies a ressource by name in particular namespace

my question is : How to use URN URI's and when ?

for exple this URN : urn:isbn:9780141036144 ,
how can i access to this book ?

Comment: To find title of book using its ISBN use this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_LookupbyISBN.html

Comment: @AedvaldTseh thank you , 

I find 2 easy websites also (very simple and useful) : 

http://www.lookupbyisbn.com/ and

https://isbnsearch.org/